# Why is Bootstrap tooltip not working with Bootstrap Toggle Plugin?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which displays a tooltip on the checkbox when the user hovers over it,

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Automatic Refresh" />


<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});

</script>
```

But when I add these library plugins from the [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) to make the checkbox a sliding switch, the tooltip stops showing up.

```
<link href="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://gitcdn.github.io/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

Here is a link to what I've got so far - http://jsbin.com/mepotaliti/edit?html,output

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: Post your browsers console log

Comment: @SatejS Does this help provide more information? - http://jsbin.com/mepotaliti/edit?html,output

Comment: @NooBskie - Noting shows up in the console in JSBin - http://jsbin.com/kamasuvani/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe not a good solution, but very fast :)

`<div rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Automatic Refresh" style="width: 100px">
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" style="width: 100%" />
</div>`

I have tried it and it works

Comment: I swapped the div for a span and it worked perfectly.